# Castle Windsor reference from NuGet doesn't work in windows phone 7 project

Tags: windows-phone-7, castle-windsor, nuget

I just added reference for Castle Windsor from NuGet and after running the application I get following expection:

> System.MissingMethodException: Could
>   not load type
>   'Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.ComponentRegistration`1'
>   from assembly 'Castle.Windsor,
>   Version=2.5.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=407DD0808D44FBDC'.
>   [Line: 0 Position: 0]    --- Inner
>   Exception --- Could not load type
>   'Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.ComponentRegistration`1'
>   from assembly 'Castle.Windsor,
>   Version=2.5.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=407DD0808D44FBDC'.

any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell Castle Windsor does not support WP7. There is a Silverlight 3 version, which you may be able to re-compile to work on WP7, but it may require (as your exception would seem to indicate) methods that are simply not present in the WP7 framework.

Alternative IoC container implementations for WP7 include:

- [Ninject](http://ninject.org/)
- [SimpleContainer](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SimpleContainer&referringTitle=Documentation) from Caliburn.Micro.
- [MicroIoC](http://microioc.codeplex.com/)
- [Funq](http://funq.codeplex.com/) by Clarius Consulting
- [OpenNetCF.IoC](http://ioc.codeplex.com/)

Comment: That is correct. Windsor does not support WP7 and I have no intention of bringing it in. We accept patches :)